# How to get object with certain property in arraylist in Jolt

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to do a Jolt transformation with a json array, and i only want the ones with certain attribute.
For example:

Input:
`{
    "characteristic": [
        {
            "name": "BrandId",
            "value": "b"
        },
        {
            "name": "status",
            "value": "SENT"
        },
        {
            "name": "statusTxt",
            "value": "sent"
        }
    ]
}`

I want output to be

```
{
"status":"SENT",
"statusTxt":"sent"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This will lead to the output you want based on your input:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "characteristic": {
        "*": {
          "name": {
            "status": {
              "@(2,value)": "status"
            },
            "statusTxt": {
              "@(2,value)": "statusTxt"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```